# Cast a border around mulpitle JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border

How would one go about to do that?

If I have

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Hello1");   
JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("Hello2");
label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
```

how do I cast a border around both labels?
Not a border for each, but one border spanning both labels.
Obviously I could draw it by hand, but that is unpractical.

I currently use flowlayout and my frame is unresizable.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your labels inside a `JPanel` with an appropriate layout manager and set the border f the panel.

The following code will result with the labels being horizontally next to each other with the given border around both.

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
panel.setBorder(...);
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.